Finding CentOS 7 Compatible Packages
I noticed that pkgs.org and similar platforms stopped hosting CentOS 7 packages.
Is there any other place to download CentOS 7 compatible RPM packages?

While you can download packages from vault.centos.org, you will at some point have issues from a Centos7 host due to the ancient TLS / CA certs DB. Also, you shouldn't be connecting an unsupported OS to the internet. If you have a modern host where you can run a TLS proxy, then you can do this....

Install stunnel on the host designated as the proxy with:

    [centos7-http]
    client = yes
    accept = 0.0.0.0:8080
    connect = vault.centos.org:443
    verifyChain = yes
    CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
    checkHost = vault.centos.org


Add the IP address of the stunnel host to /etc/hosts on the Centos 7 host:

        10.0.0.1  vault.centos.org

(note that you need to use the name of the origin host here)

amend the files in centos5:/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo and CentOS-Sources.repo to replace
http://mirror.centos.org with http://vault.centos.org:8080

remove or disable any other repos in /etc/yum.repos.d



It looks like vault.centos.org is still functional.
